# Appengine : Too many connection error

Tags: java, sql-server, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using app engine with cloud sql, 
Recently I got a hike on my app-engine error log with this message

```
java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.E...
```

I have seen many related questions here, but none of them gives a specific solution.
I have done a simple servlet wise pooling in my app like below, I want to implement a better solution than this

```
private java.sql.Connection con = null;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    con = new DbTransaction().getConnection();
}




public void doProcess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException {
// Doing my task here
}



@Override
public void destroy() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReceiveFeedDetails.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE,
                "SQL Ex  con.close>> Connection Object:" + con, e);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReceiveFeedDetails.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE,
                "Exception con.close>> Connection Object:" + con, e);

    }
}
```

This is my get connection method

```
    public Connection getConnection() {



    Connection con = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReceiveSignupDetails.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
        // e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(Configuration.CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReceiveSignupDetails.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return con;

}
```

Is there is any thing wrong in my code ..
How can I improve my connection pooling ..
Please  share you ideas, and if there is any sample of better connection pooling is available, 
any link or sample code please help......

Comment: Are you using a `jdbc:google:mysql://...` JDBC URL to connect?

Comment: @Razvan yes , the variable  Configuration.CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE inside the getConnection methods is  CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE  = "jdbc:google:rdbms://..."

Comment: The `jdbc:google:rdbms://...` is used by the old connectivity. Please switch to `jdbc:google:mysql://...`. The docs on that are here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/

Comment: @Razvan Thank you for that very valuabie info, Do There is any thing I need to care when I switch to new "jdbc:google:mysql". can you please give me a brief answer or sample, and once again thank you....

Comment: One thing worth to keep in mind is that closing the connection is important. An appengine app instance is only to have 12 simultaneously connections.

The https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/ contains an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to using debug/profile your code to find how many connection was created .
As you show i see you want to create one connection per servlet .
- How many servlets you have ?
- How many appengine instance running in same time

number of connection = servlets*running instance
it must be << 250